# Final SQL output, update into Base Table having same structure using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, insert-update

I’m working on a solution where the final output of below condition should be updated to base/main table.

Having BASE/Main table and receiving DELTA/trueup table (quarterly)
Need to run a query using Base and Delta tables and final output should store in Current Base table (query drops few records from base and adds few records from delta)
Query output contains records from Base, Delta
Tried using REPLACE INTO function- query result is stored but existing Base records are not dropped(need to drop or replace these existing Base records)

MySQL version 5.6.15

Example

Base/Main Table:

| Name | ID | Action | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | Base | 2020/08/01 |
| b | 2 | Base | 2020/08/02 |
| c | 3 | Base | 2020/08/01 |

Delta/ Trueup Table:

| Name | ID | Action | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d | 4 | add | 2021/02/01 |
| a | 1 | term | 2021/01/01 |
| a | 1 | add | 2021/02/01 |
| b | 2 | term | 2020/08/02 |
| e | 5 | add | 2021/02/01 |
| e | 5 | term | 2021/02/01 |

Output Table:

| Name | ID | Action | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | add | 2021/02/01 |
| c | 3 | base | 2020/08/01 |
| d | 4 | add | 2020/02/01 |

I have logic on obtaining the output table but need help on reflect all these records to BASE table

```
Select Base.* from
  (Select * from Base) as Base
    left outer join
  (Select * from Delta where action = 'term') as Delta
    on Base.id = Delta.id 
    where Delta.id is null) as Main

union

Select a.* from
 (Select * from Delta where action = 'add') as a
  left outer join
 (Select * from Delta where action = 'term') as b
  on a.id = b.id
  where b.id = null) as Case1

union

Select Case2_1.* from
 (Select a.* from
  (Select * from Delta where action = 'add') as a
   inner join
  (Select * from Delta where action = 'term') as b
  on a.id = b.id) as case2_1
 inner join
 (select * from Base) as Case2_2
 on case2_1.id = case2_2.id) as Case2
```

Problem - Using REPLACE INTO Base table function on top of this query is storing all the records from this query but not dropping existing records

Question - This query results Output table however I need this output records to be reflected in Base table by replacing completely (either by update or replace).

Final outcome - Base table to reflect as Output table as shown above

Comment: UNION ALL then select the latest row per name and/or id which have non-'term' action.

Comment: @Akina, thanks however your response helps in obtaining Output table. But, my question here is to update Base table with Output table records

Comment: You need at least 2 queries. `DELETE` and `INSERT .. ODKU` (if no suitable unique index then separate INSERT and UPDATE).

Comment: @Akina, thanks I can work on it. However, I would like to know is there any function which replace existing records if matches and insert new records if doesn't match? or completely replace table with query output?

Comment: *is there any function which replace existing records if matches and insert new records if doesn't match?* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html *or completely replace table with query output?* No.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution for this problem is,

Using 'Staging' Table (Temp table). Store the query Output result in Temp table and then Truncate Base table data and Insert data from Temp table.